# Is it possible to Proxy an extended class in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy

I'm trying to Proxy an inheritance structure from within a node module and allow the client to instantiate a new Class A. Currently when trying to access class B's parent methods I get `a.parentMethod is not a function`

```
handler.js ->
  module.exports = {
    get(target, key, receiver) {
      return target.getAttribute(key)
    },

    set(target, key, value, receiver) {
      return target.setAttribute(key, value)
    }
  }

A.js ->


const handler = require('handler')

class B {
  constructor(data) {
      this.data = data              
  }

  parentMethod() {
     ... do stuff
  }
}

class A extends B {
    constructor(data){
        super(data)
    }
}

module.exports = function(data) {
    return new Proxy(new A(data), handler)
}

////

const A = require('A')
var a = new A
a.parentMethod()
```

Where am I going wrong with this structure? I'm new to Proxy!

Thanks

EDIT -

Further context:

I'm trying to keep sets of properties in sync based on a valueSchema I have defined. When I set Artwork.title I need Artwork['Artwork Title'] to be updated with the same value. Likewise when I retrieve Artwork.title I get the value of Artwork['Artwork Title']. Hopefully this helps a bit. I'm stuck at the above error so I can't be sure what I've written actually works yet! I'm trying to debug why the function can't be found first...

```
class Instance {

  constructor(data) {
    this._valueAttributes = {}
  }

  setAttribute(key, value) {
    if (this._isValueAttribute(key)) {
      return this._getSetValueAttribute(key, value)
    }
    throw Error('Cannot set invalid property '+key+' on instance.')
  }

  getAttribute(key) {
    if (this._isValueAttribute(key)) {
      return this._getSetValueAttribute(key)
    }
  }

  _getSetValueAttribute(key, value) {
    let schemaKey = this._getSchemaKey(key)
    if (_.isFunction(schemaKey)) {
      return alias(data)
    }

    if (value === undefined) {
      return this._valueAttributes[schemaKey]
    }

    return this._valueAttributes[schemaKey] = value
  }

  _isValueAttribute(key) {
    return _.keys(this._valueSchema).indexOf(key) === -1
  }

}


class Artwork extends Instance {

  constructor() {
    this._valueSchema = {
      medium: 'Artwork Medium',
      title: 'Artwork Title'
    }
  }
}


///

a = new Artwork

a.title = 'thing'
a['Artwork Medium'] = 'medium';
```

I need

```
a.title == a['Artwork Title']
a['Artwork Medium'] == a.medium
```

It's very likely I've royally screwed it all up. I've assumed that I can access __valueSchema on the child from the parent. Is this not possible?

Comment: Add your `handler` implementation.

Comment: Just added, sorry I forgot!

Comment: Where are `getAttribute` and `setAttribute` defined?

Comment: Why do you think you need a proxy at all to allow inheritance and instantiation?

Comment: I've updated the question with more context. I think the issues might be that I can't access __valueSchema on the Child class from the Parent?

Comment: I think all this would be easier to solve with a few getters/setters, possibly created from decorators. You should be able to do it with a proxy as well, but you have to be careful only to route the properties you want through `get/setAttribute` instead of all accesses like method calls etc. The implementation you've shown is missing `_getSchemaKey` and `alias`, but apart from that `a.getAttribute('title') === a._valueAttributes['Artwork Title']` should work.